# How to robustly catch Controller/Action Not Found errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We're using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3.

What is the best way (most orthogonal/decoupled, simplest) to catch exceptions of the form

```
The controller for path '/MissingController/MissingAction' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

and

```
A public action method 'MissingAction' was not found on controller 'ExistingController'.
```

such that they don't reach our last resort error handling in `HttpApplication.Application_Error()`?

We're aware of a couple of partial solutions:

[Catching action method not found on controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573751/catching-action-method-not-found-on-controller) proposes two solutions to handle the case of a missing action:

1. Overriding `HandleUnknownAction()` in a base controller (downside: all controllers must inherit from that controller).
2. Implementing a custom `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` and catching `HttpException` around `InvokeAction()`, but I'm not convinced about this method as it seems that it would be catching much more than just missing action errors.

http://www.jomendez.com/2016/01/20/how-to-create-custom-controller-factory-asp-net/ proposes to implement a custom controller factory. It is not clear to me how we would redirect to our 404 error page if the controller cannot be found.

Note that we do provide custom 404 and 500 error pages via `Web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
    ...
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
        <remove statusCode="500"/>
        <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File"/>
    </httpErrors>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

but despite this exceptions are still reaching `HttpApplication.Application_Error()`.

Comment: How about Register an event on `Application_Error` at global?

Comment: @D-Shih We already override `Application_Error()` but that's not really the point. My question is about identifying then ignoring exceptions related to controllers/actions not being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We simply ended up doing the following in our `HttpApplication.Application_Error()`:

```
var ex = Server.GetLastError();
var httpException = ex as HttpException;

if (httpException == null || httpException.GetHttpCode() != 404)
{
    // Not an HttpException, or HTTP error other than 404.
    // Here: log error, send alert, etc.
}
```